# Can an item in a foreach be null

Tags: c#

I have a very simple piece code which contains a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    var valueForPropertyA = getPropertyAValue(item?.Id ?? 0);

    if(valueForPropertyA == null) {
        continue;
    }

    item.PropertyA = new PropertyADto(valueForPropertyA);
}
```

We also have some automatic code inspection tool which gives me the following warning on the above code:
`'item' is null on at least one execution path`
Is it ever possible that an `item` in a `list` is `null` or am I misinterpreting the warning?

Comment: Sure, `foreach` doesn't skip items that are null. Then you'll get a `NullReferenceException` at `item.PropertyA`. Interestingly you already used `item?.Id ?? 0`. Instead you should use `foreach(var item in list.Where(i => i != null)){}`

Comment: @Rafalon item is an object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, `foreach` doesn't skip items that are `null`. Then you'd get a `NullReferenceException` at the line `item.PropertyA = new PropertyADto(valueForPropertyA);`.

Instead you could use

```
foreach(var item in list.Where(i => i != null))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Items of reference and `nullable` value types can be null - but you can skip them manually

```
foreach(var item in list.Where(x => x != null))
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your primary question, yes, if the `IEnumerable` being enumerated by the `foreach` loop contains reference types, they can be null. For example, `List<string>` may contain null entries, as `string` can be null.

I suspect the reason you are receiving the`'item' is null on at least one execution path` message is due to the use of the null propagating operator on the following line:

```
var valueForPropertyA = getPropertyAValue(item?.Id ?? 0);
```

Later on you call:

```
item.PropertyA = new PropertyADto(valueForPropertyA);
```

The first line's `item?.Id` indicates that you expect `item` might be null. The second line does not include the null propagating operator, so the code analysis tool is warning you that while `item` might be null on the first line, you are not handling this possibility on the second line.